# submit a row data in dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I made a dynamic table with checkbox. I only want to submit the data in checked row to the form. I try to use checkbox array index but that does not work. What should I do to only submit the data in a checked row?

```js
function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  if (rowCount < 5) {
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
      var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
      newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
    }
  } else {
    alert("Maximum number of extra data is 5.");
  }
}


function deleteRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    var row = table.rows[i];
    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
    if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
      if (rowCount <= 1) {
        alert("Cannot remove all.");
        break;
      }
      table.deleteRow(i);
      rowCount--;
      i--;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="button" value="Add Option" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" />
  <input type="button" value="Remove Option" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
  <table id="dataTable">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <p>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" required="required" name="chk[]" checked="checked" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>Name of Data:</label>
            <input type="text" name="dataName">
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>Data:</label>
            <input type="text" name="data">
          </td>
        </p>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: I'm not sure you CAN submit only some of the data on the page. By definition, Submit submits the entire form. Wouldn't it be simpler to filter out the rows that don't have the checkbox checked when you get to the other end? If you want to send only certain data, you should probably be using AJAX instead.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean by submit the data, since you don't have a `form` element, nor an `input type="submit"` or `button type="submit'` in your HTML. You could go through all of the unchecked rows and disable them, since disabled fields are not submitted.